# Regex - Match all Spaces before first "="

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a large Property file where I need to quickly remove all the SPACE from the keys which got added by mistake.

I am using Sublime Text. Where I need to use regex to match the following.

What I have:

```
Rio de Janeiro=Рио де Жанейро
Rio Grande do Norte=Рио Гранде до Норте
Rio Grande do Sul=Рио Гранде направя Sul
```

What I Need:

```
RiodeJaneiro=Рио де Жанейро
RioGrandedoNorte=Рио Гранде до Норте
RioGrandedoSul=Рио Гранде направя Sul
```

I have gone through the Regex list and tried to come up with my own but failed. I need a quick solution so I am here.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share what you tried and why it did not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>CTRL + H</kbd>

**Find What**: `[ ]+(?=.*?=)`
**Replace With**:

---

[image]

---

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MUX0M7/1)

---

Explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search for:

```
[ ]+(?=[A-Za-z].*=)
```

And replace with nothing.

Explain:

```
[ ]+       : 1 or more spaces
(?=[A-Za-z].*=) : a positive lookahead 
             that asserts the space is followed by a letter ([A-Za-z]), 
             then other characters `.*` and a `=` character.
```